# Calling an array in an each loop find_by_email

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to cycle through an array in console and use find_by_email to locate the User:

```
a = [ "brian@labyrinth.com",  "lmontoymail@gmail.com"]
a.each do |email|
 u = User.find_by_email("#{a}")
 u.delete
end
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `email' for main:Object
```

Here, what I get based on the answer:

```
1.9.3p194 :035 > a = [ "brian@labyrinth.com",  "lmontoymail@gmail.com"]
 => ["brian@labyrinth.com", "lmontoymail@gmail.com"] 
1.9.3p194 :036 > a.each do |email|
1.9.3p194 :037 >     u = User.find_by_email(email)
1.9.3p194 :038?>   u.destroy
1.9.3p194 :039?>   end
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'brian@labyrinth.com' ORDER BY users.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use `#{a}`. It refers to the array, use the `email` variable passed into the loop, which refers to the email of that iteration.

```
u = User.find_by_email(email)
```

The reason you are getting the error, is because you are missing `do`.

```
a.each do |email|
  u = User.find_by_email(email)
  u.destroy
end
```

You can optimize the query by writing.

```
User.where(email: a).destroy_all
```

Comment: Hi Niels, that gives me: NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass. I've pasted the logs in my question.

Comment: Yes, the method you are looking for is called `destroy`.

Comment: `a = [ "brian@labyrinth.com",  "lmontoymail@gmail.com"]
a.each do |email|
u = User.find_by_email(email)
u.destroy
end` NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass

Comment: In that case, you don't have any users with those e-mail addresses.

Comment: Try User.where(email: a).count

Comment: This works: u = User.find_by_email("#{email}"). I corrected and accepted the answer. Thank you!

Comment: You should not have to use #{email}. That is a string interpolation. (email) and ("#{email}") means the exact same thing.

Comment: I think the interpolation inserts the quotes. How does the method determine whether email is a string or an integer? I think it would try to read it as an integer without the quotes, but not sure.

Comment: `email` is a reference, a reference to an object. Objects have a class associated, in this case, the String class.